# Perfmon - Cannot start data collector set

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, perfmon

While running perfmon on Windows 2008 server after creating a data collector set and attempting to start I receive the following error:

"The Data Collector Set or one of its dependencies is already in use."

I have two virtual machines configured the same. It runs fine on one server, but not the other.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem while Sysinternals Process Explorer was running.  Exiting Sysinternals Process Explorer fixed the problem.

Comment: You are right, Process XP is holding on that !

Answer (score 5):

In typical, this issue involves "NT Kernel Logger", which is a kernel event provider. This provider can not be accessed at the same time by multiple consumers (e.g., multiple data collector sets). Resource monitor accesses this provider.

See whether your DCS is collecting kernel logger information. Stop the resource monitor before running your DCS. If running multiple DCSs that collect kernel logger info, run one DCS at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. I found that in the Performance Monitor under Event Trace Sessions that the NT Kernel Logger was running. I stopped it and the DCS ran fine. What was weird is that on the other server that NT Kernel Logger was not there. That's why it ran with out a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a properties dialog open behind the Performance Monitor.  I closed Performance Monitor, reopened Performance Monitor, then was able to start the DCS no problem.

Answer (score 1):

This NT kernel logger file which is available in "Data collector set->Event Trace sessions-> NT kernel logger" should be stopped

Comment: Please provide reasoning as to why it should be stopped.  If you are making a suggestion for troubleshooting, please state your answer as such.

Comment: I can't offer any technical reasoning, but I can say that after stopping anything that could be conflicting (Resource Monitor, Process Explorer, even Task Manager) and not having any joy, I gave this a try and it worked. Stopping NT Kernel Logger resolves the error message in question.

Answer (score 0):

Open perfmon, go to the Reports folder.  Expand User Defined, then your custom data collector set.

Delete the .blg files